# Inno Setup Skip custom page after execution of some scripts

Tags: inno-setup

so i am currently trying to modify the setup script, 
What i was trying to do was after installing i enter in a custom page, this custom page executes 2 scritps(one for creating the database and the other for creating the tables).
while this is executing i want to display a custom label,and a continuous progress bar.
When the execution finish, i want to go directly to the finish page.
I wanto to also remove the next button.
Is this possible?

For the moment i have the custom page with a constinuous progress bar, this page appears after install.i will then add the label after finishing the progress bar part.

here is my code:

```
[CODE]
   var
   Page: TWizardPage;
   ProgressBar3: TNewProgressBar;

   procedure CreateTheWizardPages;  
   begin
       Page := CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling, 'Base de dados', 'A verificar a base de dados');
       ProgressBar3 := TNewProgressBar.Create(Page);
       ProgressBar3.Left := 5;
       ProgressBar3.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth - 5;
       ProgressBar3.Parent := Page.Surface;
       ProgressBar3.Style := npbstMarquee;
   end;

   procedure InitializeWizard();
   begin
       CreateTheWizardPages;
   end;

 //check the current page,if page equals to wpSelectCompnets, then we add the method on choose to the combobox fo types of installation
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
    //msgbox(IntToStr( CurPageID),mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then
    begin
        comboboxTypesInstalacao:=WizardForm.TypesCombo;
        WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange:=@ComboBoxChange;
    end
    else if  CurPageID = Page.ID then 
    begin
        try
           CreateDBAndTables('idontimedb.des');
        finally
        //close this custom wizard page and go to finish page
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `TOutputProgressWizardPage` page. Check [`this example`](http://pastebin.com/DzY4V7Hv).

Comment: kinda, but how can i transform it in a continuous progress bar? if i pick up the example in codedlg.iss, and execute a function that takes 3 minutes in this machine to execute, i am redirect to the nextp page before the fucntion executes, if i change the duration to the progress bar to 4 minutes, i have to wait 1 minute to go to the next page.

Comment: thaks tlama, i was not finding much information about the progress bar, once again you save my day :D